# Buck-Boost polarity

Tags: polarity, buck-boost

One of the disadvantages of a Buck-boost converter is the minus sign at the output
(Transfer function of Vo/Vin = -D/(1-D) )
My question - Why can't we just place the load rotated? Wouldn't it solve the problem?

[image]

Comment: Not all buck-boost circuits are like this so draw yours and put an image in the question.

Comment: Added a drawing :)

Comment: @Jonathan The problem is not rotating the load, it's the use of ground as reference.

Comment: It's often done that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Why can't we just place the load rotated? Wouldn't it solve the
> problem?*

For a simple load yes, you can do exactly that but, for more complex loads that require a common 0 volt line with other circuits, this cannot be done. Think of a simple power amplifier that requires + and - power rails. The circuit of an amplifier just cannot be broken into two pieces where one half of it is reversed or inverted so, no, usually this cannot be done.

So, if you need to maintain 0 volt commonality, you could always choose to have two windings and make a flyback converter from it (same duty cycle control): -

**Regular positive output flyback circuit**

[image]

**Negative output flyback circuit**

[image]